# What is the difference between .symbol file (in symbols folder) and .dsym file in ipa?

Tags: ios, debug-symbols

I found out that .dsym file is used to symbolise crash report for iOS

but

1. What is the use of .symbol file in symbols folder?
2. What are the differences?